# What type of VPS stats should I look for?

Tags: networking, vps

I have a few websites that average a total of 10,000 uniques a day across my network. I also have a few mobile apps that pull xml data maybe 5,000 calls a day. My sites aren't anything major just a few wallpaper websites and few other small sites, nothing real database intensive.

I currently own a dedicated server and I feel like it's overkill for my network. I'm looking into getting a Virtual Private Server (VPS). I was just wondering what kind of stats I should be looking for to support my network of sites.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest thing to do would be to look at your current usage on your dedicated server. Things like how much RAM it's using, disk space used, and so on, and use that as a guide for what to get on a new VPS.

One thing that I would specifically look out for is how much bandwidth you use. Dedicated boxes usually (AFAIK) have a high bandwidth limit, but VPSes usually have a smaller limit. Wallpapers also aren't exactly known for being bandwidth friendly either...

Since you already own a dedicated server, I'm going to assume that you have enough experience admin-ing your own server, so I'd suggest looking at 'true' VPSes that run on Xen or KVM. I help with admin-ing a (heavily loaded) OpenVZ-based VPS, and I hate the 'burstable' RAM, among other things.